# How to Use StandartError?

Tags: ruby, require

When I try to execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class WrongNumberOfPlayersError < StandartError ; end
class NoSuchStrategyError < StandartError ; end
```

I get the following error:

```
`<main>': uninitialized constant StandartError (NameError)
```

I assumed I need to require the StandartError file, so I wrote

```
require 'StandartError'
```

just after the line I specify my Ruby directory. As a result I had the following error:

```
/Users/nevayeshirazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- StandartError (LoadError)
from /Users/nevayeshirazi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from ./part2.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong ? Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a `StandartError` class in Ruby. You probably want [StandardError](http://apidock.com/ruby/StandardError).

Answer (score 1):

There is no class named "StandartError" as far as I know.  I think you probably meant "StandardError".  Just write this:

```
class WrongNumberOfPlayersError < StandardError; end
class NoSuchStrategyError < StandardError; end
```

By the way, it's cool to make your own Exception classes but you don't have to.  You can just write this in your code when the errors happens:

```
raise "Wrong number of players!"
raise "No such strategy!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it StandardError instead of StandartError?